# How to associate a product cost to a product in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce

I have to purchase each of my products from my manufacturer.  I want to store the cost for each product, so I can run reports and get my gross profit.  I have not found any site that demonstrates how to do this.  It seems like this should be basic for Drupal Commerce.  Am I using/searching for the wrong terminology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a new price field to your product type, call it cost, and populate it at will. That's what I do to track my cost on realmilkcheese.com.

Comment: Thanks!  What data type should I use?

Comment: Just use the Price field defined by the Commerce Price module.